# symfony form with only getter methods in entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

i want to create a forms with only getter methods in the entity... Since I am working on already existing database which does not require to store or manipulate the data.

Hence I have created Entities for the products with only Getter methods and no Setter method.

However when i create form( like search query with some dropdowns etc) it always looking for set or Add methods. Is there a possibility if i can only use getters to get the data from the database.

And I do not want data to be modified at anytime in the future.

i tried with "read_only" but it still gives an error about setter and addMethod()

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#read-only

EDIT:

I want to create a drop down ProductGroupcategory-> productSubcategory -> Product

like this(advance search): http://www.buycarspares.co.uk/

Complete Code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b2e576e69b1588e4f21

Comment: Well, if you create a form and it returns anything, those changes need to be saved "somewhere", that's why it is trying to "set" or "add" properties. Maybe those changes could be saved in a field which is not "mapped" to any entity property, in  that way you would not need a setter

Comment: came across this one article http://allwrightythen.com/ddd-with-symfony-forms/   will give it try and see how it goes, however i also need to do query builder

Comment: You could always use simple classes that has public properties. What do you do with the form data when it has been submitted? If you are doing nothing, why do you need a form?

Comment: Add all related code in the question instead of external links.

Comment: okay i updated the complte code

Answer (score 0):

Relationships require add- and get-methods simply because it is about an array or arrayCollection of an object and not about the getters or setters for normal entity properties like strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can though some people might consider the solution to be worse than the problem.  You could of course just declare your entity properties to be public.  That would avoid not only setters but getters as well.  Doctrine 2's lazy loading functionality would not work.

A more advanced approach it to realize that the form component uses a property access object to transfer data to and from your entity.  That is where the 'add' and 'set' messages are coming from.  Property access objects are also what allows you to use arrays as well as entities. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html

The form component allows you to plug in your own property access object which means that you can create your own access object which can write directly to private/protected variables using Reflection.  This, by the way, is the same technique that Doctrine 2 uses to hydrate your entities using database information.

Of course I can already hear howls of protest of this approach mostly about violating encapsulation.  But think about it for a moment before down voting.  The form component really is just persisting and retrieving the state of an entity to and from an html document.  Exactly what Doctrine 2 does.  As long as you don't misuse the technique then there is no violation.

I routinely use this approach to avoid writing endless getters and setters.  Seems to work fine in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the insight i ended up using this : 

http://www.whitewashing.de/2012/08/22/building_an_object_model__no_setters_allowed.html
and http://allwrightythen.com/ddd-with-symfony-forms/

however i ended up adding too many lines of code since i separated the form from the entity and i do see some long execution time. 

May be i will revert back to the standard getter/setters not sure

Comment: Yep.  One problem with the more "pure" approaches is that they can add a fair amount of code without adding a great deal of value for a typical request/response application.